# Can I use 'have you got' and a passive verb?

Tags: have-got

For example, can I say:

> Have you got checked the fuses by electrician?

Comment: AmE would likely say: Did you get the fuses checked by an electrician? But if you insist on the present perfect: Have you gotten the fuses checked by an electrician? BrE no longer uses _gotten_ in any context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example sentence is wrong. You could say "Have you had the fuses checked by the electrician?" or "Have the fuses been checked...?"

In informal speech I have heard something like "Have you got beaten at football again?" but in formal language "been" would replace "got".

"Have you got it solved?" works as a question to a maths student who has been struggling with a problem. So on the basis that a single example shows that something is possible, the answer to your question is "yes you can", but I had to think hard to come up with that example. It is not a common construction and not for formal use..